# Using Mapsui, how do I create a new transformation class for coordinate system read from shapefile prj file?

Tags: coordinate-system

How do I create a new transformation class compatible with MapSui.Projections.ITransformation interface using ProjNet4GeoAPI that reads the source coordindate system from a prj file.

From Mapsui source code, there is a MinimalTransformation that implements ITransformation interface to convert between SphericalMercator and WGS84.

[From Mapsui documentation](http://mapsui.com/documentation/projections.html) :
The out of the box Mapsui support for projections is limited. The MinimalProjection class only projects between SphericalMercator (EPSG:3857) and WGS84 (EPSG:4326). It is however possible to create your own Transformation. You need to implement the ITransformation interface. Within this implementation you need to use some other projection library. A recommended one is [ProjNet4GeoAPI](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI).

I can create a working the transformation class with ProjNet4GeoAPI but it implements GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.ICoordinateTransformation not Mapsui.Projection.ITransformation

```
            // (FROM SOURCE) prj name: NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001"
            ICoordinateSystemFactory csFac = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemFactory();
            string file = @"C:\DRC_Data\Arcview\USA\Townships\NYTOWNS_POLY.prj";
            string wkt= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
            var csFrom = csFac.CreateFromWkt(wkt);

            //(TO) Prj name: "WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator"
            file = @"C:\DRC_Data\Arcview\3857.prj";
            wkt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
            ICoordinateSystem csTo = csFac.CreateFromWkt(wkt);

            //Step 2) Create transformation class.
            CoordinateTransformationFactory ctFac = new CoordinateTransformationFactory();

            //To 3857                
            //var is ICoordinateTransformation
            ICoordinateTransformation ct = ctFac.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(csFrom, ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator);
```

How do I use the ICoordinateTransformation class with Mapsui?
Do I create a projection class like SphericalMercator in Mapsui.Projection
(see code below)?

From Mapsui.Projection:

```
public class MinimalTransformation : ITransformation
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, Func<double, double, Point>> _toLonLat = new Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, Point>>();
        private readonly IDictionary<string, Func<double, double, Point>> _fromLonLat = new Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, Point>>();

        public MinimalTransformation()
        {
            _toLonLat["EPSG:4326"] = (x, y) => new Point(x, y);
            _fromLonLat["EPSG:4326"] = (x, y) => new Point(x, y);
            _toLonLat["EPSG:3857"] = SphericalMercato.ToLonLat;
            _fromLonLat["EPSG:3857"] = SphericalMercator.FromLonLat;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When help from pauldendulk, here is a working code to transform layers.

- Store the supported WKT as string constants.
- Create a dictionaries of `ICoordinateTransformations` using `GetFromLatLong(WKT)` and `GetToLatLong(WKT)`.
- Create a second set of dictionaries of `Func<double, double, Point>` generated from 
  `GenerateToLatLong(string constant for WKT)` and `GenerateFromLatLong(string constant for WKT)`
- Reference the last set of dictionaries in funtions 
  `public IGeometry Transform(string fromCRS, string toCRS, IGeometry geometry)`
  `public BoundingBox Transform(string fromCRS, string toCRS, BoundingBox boundingBox)`

```
using GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems;
using GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.Transformations;
using Mapsui.Geometries;
using Mapsui.Projection;
using ProjNet.CoordinateSystems;
using ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DRC_SQLITE.Classes
{
    public class CustomMinimalTransformation : ITransformation
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, Func<double, double, Point>> _toLonLat = new Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, Point>>();
        private readonly IDictionary<string, Func<double, double, Point>> _fromLonLat = new Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, Point>>();

        private readonly IDictionary<string, ICoordinateTransformation> _ctToDict = new Dictionary<string, ICoordinateTransformation>();
        private readonly IDictionary<string, ICoordinateTransformation> _ctFromDict = new Dictionary<string, ICoordinateTransformation>();


        const string NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001 = "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",200000.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",750000.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-71.5],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",41.71666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",42.68333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",41.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]";
        const string NAD83_New_Jersey_ft_US = "PROJCS[\"NAD83_New_Jersey_ft_US\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",38.83333333333334],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-74.5],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9999],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",492125],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.30480060960121924]]";
        const string GCS_North_American_1983 = "GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]]";
        const string GCS_North_American_1927 = "GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1927\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1927\",SPHEROID[\"Clarke_1866\",6378206.4,294.9786982]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]]";
        const string NAD83_GEO = "GEOGCS[\"NAD83_GEO\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"<custom>\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]]";
        const string NAD_1983_Albers = "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_Albers\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Albers\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",500000.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",500000.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-132.5],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",61.66666666666666],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",68.0],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",59.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]";
        const string GCS_WGS_1984 = "GEOGCS[\"GCS_WGS_1984\",DATUM[\"D_WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS_1984\",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]]";
        const string NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N = "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",500000.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-99.0],PARAMETER[\"Scale_Factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",0.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]";
        const string NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_13N = "PROJCS[\"NAD83(CSRS98) / UTM zone 13N\",GEOGCS[\"NAD83_Canadian_Spatial_Reference_System\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983_CSRS\",SPHEROID[\"Geodetic_Reference_System_of_1980\",6378137.0,298.2572221009113]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",500000.0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-105.0],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]";

        //const string NAD_1983_CSRS_New_Brunswick_Stereographic = "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_CSRS_New_Brunswick_Stereographic\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983_CSRS\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983_CSRS\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Double_Stereographic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",2500000.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",7500000.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-66.5],PARAMETER[\"Scale_Factor\",0.999912],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",46.5],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]";                    

        CoordinateTransformationFactory _ctFac;
        ICoordinateTransformation _ctTo;
        ICoordinateTransformation _ctFrom;        

        public CustomMinimalTransformation()
        {            
            LoadCRS();

            _toLonLat["EPSG:4326"] = (x, y) => new Point(x, y);
            _fromLonLat["EPSG:4326"] = (x, y) => new Point(x, y);

            _toLonLat["EPSG:3857"] = SphericalMercator.ToLonLat;
            _fromLonLat["EPSG:3857"] = SphericalMercator.FromLonLat;

            _toLonLat["EPSG:CUSTOM"] = CustomProjectionToLonLat;
            _fromLonLat["EPSG:CUSTOM"] = CustomProjectionFromLonLat;

            _toLonLat["NAD83_New_Jersey_ft_US"] = GenerateToLatLong("NAD83_New_Jersey_ft_US");
            _fromLonLat["NAD83_New_Jersey_ft_US"] = GenerateFromLatLong("NAD83_New_Jersey_ft_US");

            _toLonLat["NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001"] = GenerateToLatLong("NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001");
            _fromLonLat["NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001"] = GenerateFromLatLong("NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001");

            _toLonLat["GCS_North_American_1983"] = GenerateToLatLong("GCS_North_American_1983");
            _fromLonLat["GCS_North_American_1983"] = GenerateFromLatLong("GCS_North_American_1983");

            _toLonLat["GCS_North_American_1927"] = GenerateToLatLong("NAD83_GCS_North_American_1927GEO");
            _fromLonLat["GCS_North_American_1927"] = GenerateFromLatLong("GCS_North_American_1927");

            _toLonLat["NAD83_GEO"] = GenerateToLatLong("NAD83_GEO");
            _fromLonLat["NAD83_GEO"] = GenerateFromLatLong("NAD83_GEO");

            _toLonLat["NAD_1983_Albers"] = GenerateToLatLong("NAD_1983_Albers");
            _fromLonLat["NAD_1983_Albers"] = GenerateFromLatLong("NAD_1983_Albers");

            _toLonLat["GCS_WGS_1984"] = GenerateToLatLong("GCS_WGS_1984");
            _fromLonLat["GCS_WGS_1984"] = GenerateFromLatLong("GCS_WGS_1984");

            _toLonLat["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N"] = GenerateToLatLong("NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N");
            _fromLonLat["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N"] = GenerateFromLatLong("NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N");

            _toLonLat["NAD83(CSRS98) / UTM zone 13N"] = GenerateToLatLong("NAD83(CSRS98) / UTM zone 13N");
            _fromLonLat["NAD83(CSRS98) / UTM zone 13N"] = GenerateFromLatLong("NAD83(CSRS98) / UTM zone 13N");

        }

        void LoadCRS()
        {
            _ctFromDict.Add("NAD83_New_Jersey_ft_US", GetFromLatLong(NAD83_New_Jersey_ft_US));
            _ctToDict.Add("NAD83_New_Jersey_ft_US", GetToLatLong(NAD83_New_Jersey_ft_US));

            _ctFromDict.Add("NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001", GetFromLatLong(NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001));
            _ctToDict.Add("NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001", GetToLatLong(NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001));

            _ctFromDict.Add("GCS_North_American_1983", GetFromLatLong(GCS_North_American_1983));
            _ctToDict.Add("GCS_North_American_1983", GetToLatLong(GCS_North_American_1983));

            _ctFromDict.Add("GCS_North_American_1927", GetFromLatLong(GCS_North_American_1927));
            _ctToDict.Add("GCS_North_American_1927", GetToLatLong(GCS_North_American_1927));

            _ctFromDict.Add("NAD83_GEO", GetFromLatLong(NAD83_GEO));
            _ctToDict.Add("NAD83_GEO", GetToLatLong(NAD83_GEO));

            _ctFromDict.Add("NAD_1983_Albers", GetFromLatLong(NAD_1983_Albers));
            _ctToDict.Add("NAD_1983_Albers", GetToLatLong(NAD_1983_Albers));

            _ctFromDict.Add("GCS_WGS_1984", GetFromLatLong(GCS_WGS_1984));
            _ctToDict.Add("GCS_WGS_1984", GetToLatLong(GCS_WGS_1984));

            _ctFromDict.Add("NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N", GetFromLatLong(NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N));
            _ctToDict.Add("NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N", GetToLatLong(NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N));

            _ctFromDict.Add("NAD83(CSRS98) / UTM zone 13N", GetFromLatLong(NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_13N));
            _ctToDict.Add("NAD83(CSRS98) / UTM zone 13N", GetToLatLong(NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_13N));
        }

        ICoordinateTransformation GetFromLatLong(string Wkt)
        {
            ICoordinateSystemFactory csFac = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemFactory();
            var ctFac = new CoordinateTransformationFactory();
            ICoordinateSystem csSource = csFac.CreateFromWkt(Wkt);
            ICoordinateSystem csTarget = GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84;      
            return ctFac.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(csTarget, csSource);
        }
        ICoordinateTransformation GetToLatLong(string Wkt)
        {
            ICoordinateSystemFactory csFac = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemFactory();
            var ctFac = new CoordinateTransformationFactory();
            ICoordinateSystem csSource = csFac.CreateFromWkt(Wkt);
            ICoordinateSystem csTarget = GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84;
            return ctFac.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(csSource, csTarget);
        }


        public IGeometry Transform(string fromCRS, string toCRS, IGeometry geometry)
        {
            Transform(geometry.AllVertices(), _toLonLat[fromCRS]);
            Transform(geometry.AllVertices(), _fromLonLat[toCRS]);
            return geometry; // this method should not have a return value
        }
        private static void Transform(IEnumerable<Point> points, Func<double, double, Point> transformFunc)
        {
            foreach (var point in points)
            {
                var transformed = transformFunc(point.X, point.Y);
                point.X = transformed.X;
                point.Y = transformed.Y;
            }
        }
        public BoundingBox Transform(string fromCRS, string toCRS, BoundingBox boundingBox)
        {
            Transform(boundingBox.AllVertices(), _toLonLat[fromCRS]);
            Transform(boundingBox.AllVertices(), _fromLonLat[toCRS]);
            return boundingBox; // this method not have a return value
        }

        public bool? IsProjectionSupported(string fromCRS, string toCRS)
        {
            if (!_toLonLat.ContainsKey(fromCRS)) return false;
            if (!_fromLonLat.ContainsKey(toCRS)) return false;
            return true;
        }

        public void LoadSourceWKT(string filepath)
        {
            ICoordinateSystemFactory csFac = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemFactory();
            ICoordinateSystem csSource = null;
            ICoordinateSystem csTarget = null;
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filepath) && System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                string wkt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
                csSource = csFac.CreateFromWkt(wkt);
                csTarget = GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84;
            }
            else
            {
                csSource = ProjectedCoordinateSystem.WebMercator;
                csTarget = GeographicCoordinateSystem.WGS84;
            }
            _ctFac = new CoordinateTransformationFactory();

            _ctTo = _ctFac.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(csSource, csTarget);
            _ctFrom = _ctFac.CreateFromCoordinateSystems(csTarget, csSource);
        }

        //From loaded projection file
        public Point CustomProjectionFromLonLat(double lon, double lat)
        {
            Point pt = new Point(lon, lat);
            double[] result = _ctFrom.MathTransform.Transform(pt.ToDoubleArray());
            return new Point(result[0], result[1]);
        }
        public Point CustomProjectionToLonLat(double x, double y)
        {
            Point pt = new Point(x, y);
            double[] result = _ctTo.MathTransform.Transform(pt.ToDoubleArray());
            return new Point(result[0], result[1]);
        }                

        public Func<double, double, Point> GenerateFromLatLong(string crskey)
        {
            return (x, y) => { double[] result = _ctFromDict[crskey].MathTransform.Transform(new Point(x, y).ToDoubleArray()); return new Point(result[0], result[1]); };
        }
        public Func<double, double, Point> GenerateToLatLong(string crskey)
        {
            return (x, y) => { double[] result = _ctToDict[crskey].MathTransform.Transform(new Point(x, y).ToDoubleArray()); return new Point(result[0], result[1]); };
        }

    }
}
```